# JQuery: Get value for label which belongs to input tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a label which uses `for` tag to identify which input tag it belongs to. I want to get the value of text in that label. This is the code:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" value="SSN" /><label for="radio2">SSN</label>
```

I need the value contained by the label tag: i.e. SSN.. I have this so far:

```
var lbText = $('label[for="' + $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').("out of ideas over here!") + '"]').html()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('label[for="' + $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').attr("id") + '"]').html()
```

here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKb3M/1/)

Comment: .html() returns the span class of the label, you might just edit that to text()..that said, it works fine!

Comment: depend's on what you have in your label, it works for current case in jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want..:)

```
$('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').next().text();
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/qTHEy/)